# Not able to edit search engine robots from admin

Tags: seo, magento2.2.6

I am trying to edit search engine robots from content and theme configuration but no option to edit.

I am trying to enable the same section for my theme.

I am using v2.2.6

Is there any backend setting from the configuration that I am missing?

Please guide on this...  I am trying to edit under theme Magenest cf

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to

> Store > Configuration > Catalog > XML Sitemap

and scroll down to `Search Engine Submission Settings`, you’ll find a setting that enables you to add the sitemap: directive to your `robots.txt` file

[image]

If you enable this, the URL towards your main sitemap `index` file (the one that contains just two URL-s, the URLs of your actual URL sitemap and image sitemap) will be added to the `robots.txt` file that’s dynamically generated on your website and if you visit `yourstore.com/robots.txt` you’ll see.

> Content > Design > Configuration

[image]

**In here you can open an accordion section titled “Search Engine Robots”.**

[image]

**PRO TIP**: If you’re having trouble saving the configuration at this step locally, try [this fix](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5666#issuecomment-233195345).

Comment: so should I keep  search engine submission settings from xml site map to yes or no?

Comment: Yes, read the description

Comment: and if answer solves your concern then mark as right, which will help future readers.

Comment: I have updated question with image ... It is not yet editable ... I kept search engine submission settings from xml site map to no